# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'maps')?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-maps

[![this image showing the code snippet:
it shows a google map with a marker, the marker isn't working  because of an error that appears, that error says: map.tsx:42 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'maps')][]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMyLz.png)

Answer (score 1):

The "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined" error indicates multiple requests to the API on the same page. This is generally caused by a combination of plugins or plugin and theme both having a Google Maps API functionality.  The resolution would be loading the maps once.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overview#Loading_the_Maps_API